# Glyphicon files not found in rails project

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using glyphicons in my project for a plugin. I keep getting this error for this file path coming back with nothing. But it seems to be the exact file path.
Is my file path incorrect?

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)



@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('./fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('./fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kggsO.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your fonts are in `app/assets/fonts`, you should be able to reference the font path using `font-url` with the filename - no relative path required:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src:font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src:font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  ...
}
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you may need to explicitly add `app/assets/fonts` to your assets path in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Here's a nice resource detailing web fonts with the Rails asset pipeline: https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570

Thanks!